# Add class in function

Tags: jquery

why i getting error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &"

```
$('.item').click(function() { 
  &('.products').addClass('move-to-left-list');
  $('#demo').addClass('move-to-left');
});
```

Comment: `&('.products')` change to `$('.products')`

Comment: please try to solve the problem yourself before posting a question here. This is obvious

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.item').click( function() {
        $('.products').addClass('move-to-left-list');
        $('#demo').addClass('move-to-left');
    });
```

Note:-

`&('.products')` changed to `$('.products')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<script>
$('.item').click( function() {
        $('.products').addClass('move-to-left-list');
        $('#demo').addClass('move-to-left');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Replace your & from second row to $ because jquery var refrence is defined by $ **

```
$('.item').click(function() { 
 --> $('.products').addClass('move-to-left-list'); <-- //replace this line
  $('#demo').addClass('move-to-left');
});
```